Flask app not rendering Model Explainer dashboard

Hi- Can you please review the code and let me know where its going
wrong? Its not rendering or showing the dashboard in the app Its
published in azure webapp,its building the dashboard but not showing
anything in the app

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request,jsonify,Blueprint,Markup
import json
import requests
import os

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer, ExplainerDashboard
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

app = Flask(__name__)

dashboard_blueprint = Blueprint('dashboard', __name__)

@dashboard_blueprint.route("/explainer")
# @app.route('/explainer')
def explainer_dashboard():


    Master_Data.drop(['date_generated'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    Master_Data = Master_Data.loc[:, Master_Data.columns.isin(unique_elements)]

    # Step 5: Split the data into train and test sets
    X = Master_Data.copy()
    y = Master_Data['Target']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.drop(['Target','Id','ref'], axis=1), y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    # after all the slicing and splitting of DataFrames and Series
    X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True)
    X_test = X_test.reset_index(drop=True)
    y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop=True)
    y_test = y_test.reset_index(drop=True)

    # Train a RandomForest model
    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, max_depth=5)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Step 6: Set up the explainer dashboard
    explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test, labels=['Not Homeless', 'Homeless'], index_name="Id", target="Homelessness")
    db= ExplainerDashboard(explainer, title="Homelessness Model Explainer", importances=True,
                                model_summary=True,
                                contributions=True,
                                whatif=False,
                                shap_dependence=True,
                                shap_interaction=True,
                                decision_trees=True)

    return db.app.index()

# Register the Blueprint
app.register_blueprint(dashboard_blueprint, url_prefix='/dashboard')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)

